# Create an array of string with an element from a list

Tags: arrays, list, java-8

There is a `list` with four string in it --> employee details ( IDs, name, manager IDs, and so on -- all of string type).

First need to filter the list with distinct IDs.

From which need to take the ID from each object in the list and store it as an array of IDs. This would just be all the distinct ID of employee that I then pass off to a different function.

```
List<ViewData> list = getDataList();
list = list.parallelStream()
            .filter(distinctByKey(ViewData::getId))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I was thinking of creating a local string array and use a forEach to collect the required string from each object and store it as an element in the list and finally pass it onto the function. How do I go about it? I have tried forEach on the list and am not able to get how to iterate through each object and store the value into the array.

*Something along this:*

```
String[] allIds;
list.forEach(id -> allIds[] = getId);
```

Comment: Please provide input and output details.

Comment: can u clarify? data store on the string? The list contains filtered employee details ( IDs, name, manager IDs, and so on). I want to take out the employee's ID from each object in the list and store it as an array of IDs. This would just be the ID of employee that match my constraints that I need to pass off to a different function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you are looking for is:

```
String[] allIds = 
    getDataList().parallelStream() 
                 .map(ViewData::getId)
                 .distinct()
                 .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: what is the `ViewData` ? Can i substitute `getDataList()` with `list` that contains my filtered list and `getId()` would be the getter that returns the `id` from the list?

Comment: @BharathYes `ViewData` is a class that appears in your question, so you should know what it is better than I do.

Comment: @BharathYes I assumed that `.filter(distinctByKey(ViewData::getId))` was a failed attempt to filter out duplicate Ids. You don't need it if you use `map` followed by `distinct` as I suggested.

Comment: thanks, I got confused with `ViewData`. and distinctByKey is a function that was previously being used. Will confirm once integrated and tested... It would be helpful to find resources/docs to learn more about programming like this...Am trying to get into this without experience.

Comment: can the list be `filter`ed based on one column value and then use `map` to collect a different column value to be stored in the string? Asking like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483996/extracting-db-column-data-with-filter-and-map-in-java8)