# Extracting db column data with filter and map in Java8

Tags: java, filter, java-8, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

A table about employees has following data: employee Id, employee name, their manager's Id and their team members' Id. Each employee would have multiple entries based on their team size. Say an employee with 5 other members in their team would have five rows with the employee and manager id repeated each with one team member's id.

Sample table:

```
employeeId | employeeName | managerId | teamEmployeeId |
-------------------------------------------------------
1000       | Alex         | 4000      | 1101           |
1200       | Bran         | 4100      | 1301           |
1200       | Bran         | 4100      | 1302           |
1000       | Alex         | 4000      | 1102           |
1200       | Bran         | 4100      | 1303           |
1000       | Alex         | 4000      | 1103           |
1200       | Bran         | 4100      | 1304           |
1200       | Bran         | 4100      | 1305           |
1000       | Alex         | 4000      | 1104           |
```

The goal is to split each employees' team IDs (with the manager id too) into a separate array to be used later.

Expected result:

```
allIds:
1000
1200

teamIds for "Alex" :
1101
1102
1103
1104
4000

teamIds for "Bran" :
1301
1302
1303
1304
1305
4100
```

The first part of getting unique employee ids is working (based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59470049/create-an-array-of-string-with-an-element-from-a-list/59470099)). But trying to split the team members by using the employee id returns the first value, but the correct number of times. Say: a team with 5 returns an array of five with the first member's id in all. Manager's id isn't being added.

The code I am using:

```java
List<ViewData> list = getDataList();
        
String[] allIds = list.parallelStream()
    .map(ViewData::getId).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);
        
System.out.println(allIds.length + "\n");
        
for (String id : allIds) {
            
    String[] teamIds = list.parallelStream()
        .filter(row -> row.getId().equals(id))
        .map(ViewData::getTeamId).distinct()
        .toArray(String[]::new);
            
    teamIds = Arrays.copyOf(teamIds, teamIds.length+1 );
    teamIds[teamIds.length] = list.parallelStream()
        .filter(obj -> obj.getId().equals(id))
        .map(ViewData::getManagerId).toString();
    System.out.println(teamIds.length + "\n");
}
```

I understand this is a logical error. All the docs I have referred for filter() shows the syntax is correct. My understanding is the filter() returns the entire row whose id matches with the one I am looping through and the map() takes out the team member's id from that row and finally everything is returned as a string array.

Where have I gone wrong? Writing the code or understanding how these functions work?

---

edit:

> if a table like this causes duplicates/repeat rows(particularly the exact number of time it is supposed to be present):

a view without a primary key (i.e., no guaranteed unique column ) needs a composite primary key derived by combining two columns that would then be unique.

- Create a separate `@Embeddable` class for composite key combo
- Add it to main model class:
  `@EmbeddedId private UniqueId uniqueId;`
- Proceed with the exisiting logic as in the answer:

```java
for (String id : allIds) {
    String[] teamIds = list.stream()
        .filter(row -> row.getUniqueId().getId().equals(id))
        .map(obj -> obj.getUniqueId().getTeamEmployeeId())
        .toArray(String[]::new);

    teamIds = Arrays.copyOf(teamIds, teamIds.length + 1);
    teamIds[teamIds.length - 1] = list.stream()
        .filter(obj -> obj.getUniqueId().getId().equals(id))
        .map(ViewData::getManagerId).findFirst().orElse("");            
    
    String empName = list.stream()
        .filter(obj -> obj.getUniqueId().getId().equals(id))
        .map(ViewData::getName).findFirst().orElse("");
}
```

---

Update:

This was a terribly complicated solution from a limited understanding of data structures. A simpler (slightly redundant) solution using Set's auto de-duplication:

```java
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> res = new HashMap<>();
employeeDetails.forEach(o-> {
    Integer empId = o.empId;
    if(!res.containsKey(empId)) res.put(empId, new HashSet<>());
        res.get(empId).addAll(Set.of(o.teamMemberId, o.managerId));
});
return res;
```

Even this isn't a very optimal solution. It makes a lot of access and modification to the `res` map and its values. But in contrast to the previous approach this only goes through the list of records once. Some basic bench marking on both solutions shows the newer approach is 3-4 times faster for record of 1000 size and 10x for size in 100s.

But going 5000+ brings both closer as they both get bogged down by the number of objects created to store the results and their access.

Comment: Can you add sample input with the corresponding expected output? It's hard to understand your description.

Comment: @Eran added a sample i/p -> o/p. right now this code only returns the first teamId for each employee. including the manager ID is optional. But is the filter and map combo format is correct? I am having issues with that. Filtering based on one column and taking a different column into the array.

Comment: What should the type of the output be?

Comment: @Eran need it as `String[]`

Comment: How can you store in a single String array the list of team IDs for each employee ID? It sounds like you need a `Map<String,List<String>>` or `Map<String,String[]>`.

Comment: @Eran each employeeid has a seperate `String[]`. So for a table with two distinct employees there would be three string arrays. One for list of employees and then two array of team member Ids for each employee Id.

Comment: need to invoke a different function by passing a `String[]` as argument. for each employee I would invoke the function with their `team member Id` array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question and comments, what you need is:

```
for (String id : allIds) {
    String[] teamIds = list.parallelStream()
                           .filter(row -> row.getId().equals(id))
                           .map(ViewData::getTeamId).distinct()
                           .toArray(String[]::new);

    teamIds = Arrays.copyOf(teamIds, teamIds.length + 1);
    teamIds[teamIds.length - 1] = list.parallelStream()
                                      .filter(obj -> obj.getId().equals(id))
                                      .map(ViewData::getManagerId)
                                      .findFirst()
                                      .orElse(null);

    System.out.println(teamIds.length + "\n");
}
```

Comment: did the `teamIds.length-1` after getting a `outofbounds` exception. but the proper value isn't being filtered and mapped in either of the `list.streams.filter.map`

`.filter(obj -> obj.getId().equals(id)).map(ViewData::getManagerId)` is what I was using but this is storing the first matching value into the string[] over and over. So applying distinct returns a array of size 1. So `alex` gets `1101` and `bran` gets `1301`. That is why I thought it was a logic issue with `map` part.

Comment: @BharathYes Are you sure that your input contains multiple distinct team Ids for the same emp Ids? If so, it shouldn't return a single value. What happens if you remove the `distinct()`?

Comment: Yes. without distinct it returns the first value repeated the right amount of time. So `alex` gets `1101` four times and `bran` gets `1301` five times. I am trying to split this into two. Filter and create a `List` and then map the values of of that new `List`

Comment: @BharathYes it doesn't make sense. Perhaps your input list (returned by `getDataList()`) doesn't contain what you think it does. Did you try to print that `List` (assuming `ViewData` overrides `toString()`)?

Comment: You are right. Sorry. My data after fetching is incorrect